# Cant connect raspberry pi to internet over SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to get Internet access in raspberry pi after connecting it to my laptop via SSH. I have wireless internet access on my laptop. Can I share my wireless internet with raspberry via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must route your traffic to the laptop on the RPi (if not done), using [route](http://linux.die.net/man/8/route) with something like:

```
sudo add default gw IP_OF_YOUR_LAPTOP dev eth0
```

Second, you must configure your firewall to forward that traffic on your laptop to the appropriate interface using [iptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) (there are many [tutos/howtos](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/)...)